# How to split int in a 5 random numbers?

Tags: javascript, math

How to split int in a 5 random numbers?

for example:

**input** = 10

**output** = 2,1,5,1,1 ( total = 10 )

Thank you!

Comment: `1,1,1,1,input-4` (I chose those numbers at random)

Comment: deduct random nrs that are small than the (decreased) int for 4 times, and the final nr is the left over value

Comment: actually, it is a fun algorithm to write, pitty it was put on hold already (I don't see it as to broad, it gives input and output, there might be a few criteria missing, but no close reason exists anymore to close it, and the downvotes should have been enough)  (I don't know how I managed to post the answer, I just saved the snippet, and could click post as answer :s)

Comment: Take a look at [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you will still edit your question with some more criteria and what you have tried so far, however, following implementation follows:

- No 0 numbers ;
- The resulting array should be exactly the requested numbers long ;

It doesn't check if the division is possible, theoretically, the `targetNumber - totalSumNumbers >= 0` has to apply, if it doesn't, you will get incorrect results, it should rather throw an error.

```js
/**
 * @method createRandomSumNumbers
 * @param {int} the number that should be able to be summed
 * @param {int} the size of the array that should be left at the end
 * @returns {[int,...,totalSumNumbers]} an array containing up totalSumNumbers of integers
 */
function createRandomSumNumbers( targetNumber, totalSumNumbers ) {
  if (targetNumber - totalSumNumbers < 0) {
    throw "Cannot create the desired output if the targetNumber is smaller than the totalSumNumbers";
  }
  if (targetNumber <= 0 || totalSumNumbers <= 0) {
    throw "Inputted numbers should be greater than 0";
  }
  let result = [], rest = targetNumber;
  for (let i = 1; i < totalSumNumbers; i++) {
    // to make sure no 0s sneak in, the random pattern should be
    // the rest value minus the number of numbers that should be created + the current I step
    // and the +1 to exclude 0s
    let value = parseInt(Math.random() * ( rest - totalSumNumbers + i) ) + 1;
    result.push( value );
    rest -= value;
  }
  result.push( rest );
  return result;
}

console.log( createRandomSumNumbers( 10, 5 ) );

// this should always return [1,1,1,1,1]
console.log( createRandomSumNumbers( 5, 5 ) );

// throws an error
console.log( createRandomSumNumbers( 4, 5 ) );
```

Comment: Your Answer doesn't works with floats , For example if I want this : createRandomSumNumbers( 5, 10 ) it's throws an error.

But createRandomSumNumbers( 5, 10 )  is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @OyshoBoy it's upside down, read the param list. You are also asking for an `int`, not for a `float`, however you could change it to fit float as well if you would just remove the `parseInt` and remove the first if check, and quite possibly the +1 as well, but like I said, your question didn't ask for float, it clearly showed ints in the result

Comment: oh sure! Marked as answered with your answer! Thank you man very much! But just replace parseInt with parseFloat doesn't helped, it's returning negative values sometimes...